# data bindings aren't updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this [site](http://therealplayer1.com/new/#/server-browser) which is basically a server-monitor for a small game called "Armagetron Advanced". This server-monitor is supposed to reload the json every time I come back to the site.

Here's the code for my app:

```
controller('ServerBrowserController', function($scope, ServerDataFactory) {

    $scope.loadServers = function() {
        $scope.ServerData = ServerDataFactory.getServerDataWithQ();
        //promise.then(function(data) {
            //$scope.$apply(function() {
                //$scope.ServerData = data;
            //});
        //});
    }        

    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
        if(document[hidden] == false) {
            $scope.loadServers();
        }
    }, false);

    $scope.loadServers();
}).
factory('ServerDataFactory', function($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var factory = {};

    factory.getServerDataWithQ = function() {
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/new/app/serverxml_to_json.php' }).
            success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
            error(function(data) {
                alert("Couldn't load xml data.");
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };

    return factory;
}).
```

The http query works fine the first time, but as soon I come back to the site and the php script is queried again, the bindings aren't updated, even though the data is different. I thought this would automatically work as promises internally call $apply on the scope, but apparently it doesn't. Hence I tried to call $apply manually:

```
  $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.ServerData = data;
  }
```

But that also didn't work because now it said that "$digest [is] already in progress". The weird thing was tho, I didn't even work on the first try, which it used to do without the $apply. After doing some research on the digest problem, one of the solutions suggested trying the following:

```
$scope.$$phase == "$digest" || $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.ServerData = data;
}
```

But that also didn't work because $scope.$$phase was always set to "$digest", no matter if it was the initial data loading or the n-th time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `deferred` object in ServerDataFactory, so every call to `getServerDataWithQ` tries to resolve **the same** deferred, but a deferred can be resolved only once. So it's a simple fix: move `var deferred = $q.defer();` into `getServerDataWithQ()`.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that. such a stupid mistake...

anyway, thanks a lot :)